# Need to check if the string is the same when read backwards

Tags: c++

I have no clue what is wrong here. I'm a totally new though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int string_length;
    string word, wordb;
    cout << "Type in a word\n";
    cin >> word;
    string_length = word.length();
    for (int i=1; i < (string_length+1); i++)
        wordb = wordb + word.at(i);
    if (word == wordb)
        cout << "The word is the same in any direction.\n";
    else 
        cout << "The word is not the same in any direction.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if it's obvious.

Comment: `i` should start at 0, not 1.  Arrays in c++ are zero based.

Comment: *You* have no clue what's wrong? Then how should *we* have a clue?! Do you at least have an error message?

Comment: this should throw an exception. Read what it says and debug.

Comment: Did you try to debug through it? You can set watch expressions on variables in the debugger.

Comment: You're construction `wordb` in the same order as `word`. After fixing the indices (0-based, not 1-based), think about accessing the characters starting from the *end* of `word`, and working backwards.

Comment: At first I did so, but in that case I get na error "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."

Comment: A possibility: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal

Comment: Another hint: `std::reverse` to reverse the string.

Comment: @RedAlert if an exception is thrown and there is no matching `catch`, then `std::terminate` is called. It's QoI whether the compiler decides to step in and display details of the exception in this case (i.e. the compiler provides a default `terminate_handler` that reads the exception by magic).

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to "construct" the `wordb` from `word`, you can directly compare the letters one by one in one iteration:

```
for (int i=0; i < string_length; i++) {
    if letter_in_pos[i] == letter_in_pos[string_length-i-1]
      looks good, do nothing
    else
      break! word is not a palindrome!
}
```

and finally, if the word is a real palindrome, you only need to go to the middle of the word (since it's symmetric).

Comment: @Pavel so you should correct your answer, letter_in_pos[ i] == letter_in_pos[ string_length - i - 1]

Answer (score 1):

chris suggested the use of `std::equal`. Here is an example of how that would look like:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool is_palindrome(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin());
}

int main()
{
    std::string word;
    std::cout << "Type in a word\n";
    std::cin >> word;

    if (is_palindrome(word))
        std::cout << "The word is the same in any direction.\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "The word is not the same in any direction.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to write

```
if ( word == string( word.rbegin(), word.rend() ) )
//...
```

or

```
wordb.assign( word.rbegin(), word.rend() );

if ( word == wordb )
//...
```

As for your approach then the correct loop will look as

```
for ( string::size_type i = word.length(); i != 0;  )
    wordb.push_back( word[--i];
```

or

```
for ( string::size_type i = word.length(); i != 0;  )
    wordb += word[--i];
```

Comment: or `wordb = word; std::reverse(wordb.begin(), wordb.end());` No need to write your own loops for this.

Comment: @tillaert It is too compound.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know to do this would be to use the simple logic of A[DeltaX]==B[-DeltaX], While DeltaX <= 1/2 Length.  Where A is your first Character, B is your last character, and DeltaX is your step, which should never take you past 1/2 the length of the string (as you will be comparing the first half to the second half).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int string_length;
int last_character;
bool found_mirror = true;

cout << "Type in a word\n";
cin >> word;

string_length = word.length();
// if the char count is less that 2 than technically it's true
if (string_length < 2)
    return true;

last_character = string_length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= (string_length / 2); i++)
{
    if (word[i] != word[last_character - i])
    {
        found_mirror = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (found_mirror)
    cout << "The word is the same in any direction.\n";
else 
    cout << "The word is not the same in any direction.\n";
return 0;
}
```